# How can I make a Bash script that sudo's all by itself in OS X on a standard account, assuming I know the root password?

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, sudo

Okay, for reasons I won't get into (because they're rather silly), I need to make a shell script that will enable SSH on OS X every, say, 10 seconds. Yes, I know it sounds silly/pointless, but there is a reason.

Just for clarification, I know the root password (I can successfully `login root` in Terminal), but the script will be run at the login of a non-administrator user.

The script will run as a launch agent on a standard (**non-administrator**) account, and needs to somehow elevate itself to root (whose password I happen to know) so it can enable SSH.

I've tried using `expect`, but to no avail (it just refuses to work on OS X), and it seems the only other option to pass a password in a Bash script is to use `echo $pass | sudo -S $command`, but then it's just a standard user trying to `sudo`, and it doesn't work.

I've tried `echo $pass | sudo -S login root`, `echo "1234" | sudo -S su root`, and `echo "1234" | sudo -S su`, but they all just return "Sorry, try again.", even though it is echoing the correct password, and I know because I can successfully `login root`.

Anyways, I guess my question is, how can I specify to Bash that I want to `sudo` as root, as opposed to the current, standard account that is running the script. Or otherwise, how can I write a script, that, when run under a normal user, will elevate itself to root or at least an administrative account, all by itself, without the need for user input; assuming I know the password to root, of course.

I know the scenario sounds really "why would you ever need a script to do this", but just please help me; I would be really grateful. [Here](http://pastebin.com/K6FmsBVK)'s my current, non-working code.

Comment: what is the value of `$pass`?  Is it the root password or the password of the user under which the script runs?  Because `sudo` needs user's password, not the root password.

Comment: Actually yeah, I just realized that.

I think I might just use edit the sudoers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of storing the password inside your script.. just use the `NOPASSWD` option in the `/etc/sudoers` file.  You'll want a line in there like:

```
username ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Then in your script just do:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

No `expect` or any weirdness necessary.

P.S. Why do you need to do this!?

Comment: Beat me to it. Allow `sudo` to work without entering the password. You should limit it to just the commands you need. Entering the password when you sudo is sort of a safety device. It warns you that you're about to do something that could cause massive havoc.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the setuid flag on your script?

Comment: You can't setuid an interpreted script. You would have to setuid the interpreter.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that?

Comment: @jordanm Oh thanks for the precision, didn't know that. Actually it makes sense for security reasons ;)

Comment: @cookiesui : there is plenty of tutorials on Google for that. As jordanm said anyway you can't set the setuid bit on a script. But if it is possible in your case, you may probably set it on an executable of your own (convert your script to a simple C program for example, compile it then try to set the setuid bit o it). Loads of tutorials on Google for that too.